# How to make table aritary number of columns in Matlab

Tags: matlab, file, printf

I am trying to make a table and write complex data to the file however Matlab is not shifting the column so whatever I do just I have two columns for real and complex data. I would like to have two columns (real and complex) for each column. So assume my matrix is X:

```
X=[1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8; 9 10 11 12];
```

Here is the function and output I will get:

```
function f_save(in)
FID=fopen('C:\Users\mehdi\Music\Saved_file.txt','wt');
[m,n]=size(in);
for ii=1:n

        for jj=1:m 

           fprintf(FID,'%3.10g  %3.10gi \n',[real(in(jj,ii)) imag(in(jj,ii))]);
        end
     fprintf('\t \t');

end
fclose(FID);
```

The output is:

```
  1    0i 
  5    0i 
  9    0i 
  2    0i 
  6    0i 
 10    0i 
  3    0i 
  7    0i 
 11    0i 
  4    0i 
  8    0i 
 12    0i
```

But I want the output to be divided into 6 columns so the first column has its own imaginary and real part and so on.

Can anyone tell me why it is not shifting to the next column even when I have `fprintf('\t \t');`

Comment: how exactly should it look in the end? you have a 3x4 input matrix (X). so you want 3 rows with each 4 complex numbers? that would be 3 rows with 8 columns. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes. So column 1 should be really two column real and imaginary and the same for other columns so 3 rows and 8 columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all real() and imag() work the other way around, they get the real and imaginary part of a complex number and dont make a real number to a complex. to make it imaginary just use ' i ':

```
a=1+2i
real(a) % is 1
imag(a) % is 2
```

if you just want to write numbers to a file matlab doesnt need to be aware of what is real and imaginary. you might have been aware of that, but in that case taking the real numbers 1 to 12 is a wierd example.

second you should swap the for-loops. now it is doing something for every column and in that for every row, but you have to write the other way around.

```
FID=fopen('Saved_file.txt','wt');
in=[1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8; 9 10 11 12];
[m,n]=size(in);
for ii=1:m %for each row
        for jj=1:n %for each column
           fprintf(FID,'%3.10g %3.10gi \t',[real(in(ii,jj)) imag(in(ii,jj))]);
        end
     fprintf(FID,'\n');
end
```

if you want to you can add \t (tabulators). but you need an \n (newline ) at the end of the row-for-loop

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question you want this:

```
for ii=1:n
        for jj=1:m 
           fprintf(FID,'%3.10g\t%3.10gi\t',[real(in(jj,ii)) imag(in(jj,ii))]);
        end
     fprintf(FID,'\n');
end
```

Which give you an output of `m*2` columns.

Comment: This does not work. it prints everything in one row for me. Do you think can anything be wrong with Matlab or the way I am writing to the file I am using 'wt'. By the way I need 2*n columns not 2*m columns

Comment: When I print the output to Matlab workspace I get 2*m columns but in the file I see only one row of data. Where do you think is the underlying problem

Comment: i think there is missing the FID in the 2nd fprintf